# React hooks - set state of Parent from child via function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

guys I am just learning React and I decide to do try to build Hero Database and I encounter a problem.

When I click on any of Heroes, Bio state and Display state updates with data about the hero and modal window pop up with more information about him. But I don't know how to close it. I have Modal as a separate component and when I am trying calling the function (updateDisplay) from child component. which should set State of Display to False it just doesn't work :/

Heroes.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Hero from "./Hero";
import styled from "styled-components";

function Heroes(props) {
  const [Bio, setBio] = useState([]);
  const [Display, setDisplay] = useState(false);

  const SingleHeroCont = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: center;
  `;

  const content = props.data.map((Hero) => (
    <SingleHeroCont
      onClick={() => {
        setBio(Hero);
        setDisplay(true);
      }}
      key={Hero.id}
    >
      <h1>{Hero.name}</h1>
      <img src={Hero.images.sm} alt="Sorry guys"></img>
    </SingleHeroCont>
  ));

  const updateDisplay = () => {
    setDisplay(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="heroes_cont">
      <Hero updateDisplay={updateDisplay} Display={Display} BioData={Bio} />
      {content}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Heroes;
```

Hero.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

function Hero({ Display, updateDisplay, BioData }) {
  const HeroAbsolute = styled.div`
    display: ${(props) => (props.showBio ? "block" : "none")};
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
  `;


  return (
    <HeroAbsolute showBio={Display}>
      <div className="hero_bio_cont">
        <h1>{BioData.name}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => updateDisplay}>Close</button>
        <div className="hero_bio_appearance">
          <div>
            <img></img>
            <div>
              <h2>{BioData.powerstats?.power}</h2>
              <h2></h2>
              <h2></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </HeroAbsolute>
  );
}

export default Hero;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onClick={() => updateDisplay}>Close</button>
```

As I see, the above code is not working to call `updateDisplay` function.

Correct usage would be

```
<button onClick={() => updateDisplay()}>Close</button>
```

Or

```
<button onClick={updateDisplay}>Close</button>
```

Please refer to the arrow function tutorial for the second case.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Such a stupid mistake and I spend like 2 hours on it ;)